# How do you link SQL values to a dropdown menu

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu that uses the information from the first column of a SQL table to populate it. How would I link the data from the database to my dropdown menu through python and flask?

I've tried linking the table results through an if statement in python. however this doesn't show any information
It also comebacks with 'image_name' is not defined for the @app.route section, how would i define it?

Python

```
def db_read(image_name):
    #print("Filename: ", filename )
    file_name=[]
    try:
        with sql.connect("translation.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute('SELECT imagename FROM translations ORDER BY imagename ASC', (filename,))
            con.commit()
            file_name = cur.fetchall()
            # print("-----------------------------------------")
            # print("ROWS: ", rows)
            print("reading from DB successful")
    except:
        con.rollback()
        print("error in insert image name operation")
    finally:
        con.close() 
    return file_name

@app.route('/selectImage', methods=['GET','POST'])
def selectImage():
    file_name = db_read(image_name)
    print("image name: ", file_name)
    return render_template("selectImage.html")
```

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown" action="getfileHelper" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data- 
   toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      {% for x in file_name %}
         <option value="{{ x }}"{% if loop.first %} SELECTED{% endif %}>{{ x }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      Dropdown button
   </button>
</div>
```

SQL is in format (filename, origtext, translation) and is called 'translations.db'

Comment: You don't need the `if loop.first` check. By default the first option is selected.

Comment: `cur.fetchall` returns a list of lists. So you need to output `x[0]`.

Comment: you use the variable `image_name`. But where does this variable come from? Then in your template you do an iteration on a variable `file_name` that you did not return in your `render_template`.